# Is it possible to set two different user accounts on different HD or partition?

Tags: 12.04, users

I have installed ubuntu in a 20 GB HD, and I have two more HD, (160 GB HD and 80 GB HD). But in order to have my data safe (and more easily configure/change/alternate OS system). I want to set two user in the other two HD, respectly. I can setup a user in a different HD (apart from de system HD), but no idea how to set up the other user in the remaining HD...

I didn´t find how to set the two user in two HD.

Any help? or idea where to find how to set it up?. I would prefer GUI configuration...

Regards!

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a user new user.
2. Open a terminal.
3. Move the new user's "home" directory to the partition or hard disk you desire...

   `$ sudo mv /home/user_home_dir_name /path_to_new_partition`
4. Create a symbolic link in the `/home` folder to the user's "home" directory...

   `$ sudo ln -s /path_to_new_partition/user_home_dir_name /home/user_home_dir_name`
5. Log out and login as the new user.

Answer (score 0):

Although not an **exact match** to your situation, **[this is a solution that can assist you here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206/how-can-i-move-the-home-directory-to-a-separate-partition)** (previous StackExch answer on the Unix site).

In case it isn't obvious, the slight changes you'll need to make to those steps are as follows (adjust to your particular situation as needed):

- He uses `/home` as the mountpoint for the joint partition.  You will use `/home/USERNAME1` for drive 1 and `/home/USERNAME2` for drive 2 instead of a common `/home`.

  - This will be done using **`/etc/fstab`** to ensure the drives are mounted each boot automatically.
- According to **your comment**:

  > "...(and more easily configure/change/alternate OS system)."

  you plan to possibly re-install or dual-boot your Ubuntu install and use the same files.  I've never tried this personally, though I see no reason for it to fail.  But let me know how that goes for you :)
- If your **users** are **already created** you'll need to either move the home directories using:

  ```
  sudo usermod -d /path/to/drive1/mountpoint USERNAME1
  ```

  or mount the partitions somewhere while using symbolic linking to direct the filesystem to the correct place.

  - I see *no point* in this considering you can just as easily `mount` the drive directly to the `/home/USERNAME1` directory, skipping the extra middle-man, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Note, here is an approach will modify the user's home directory, instead of creating a sym-link to the new location.

1. Create a user new user.
2. Open a terminal.
3. Move the new user's "home" directory to the partition or hard disk you desire...

   `$ sudo usermod -m -d /path_to_new_partition/user_name user_name`
4. Log out and login as the new user.